# Debugging console.log on object

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, console.log

In `console.log` I received an output on object `canHandle: [Function: canHandle]` and in second `canHandle: [Function]`. Whats the difference in between?

```
const SessionEndedRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    }
};
```

returns `canHandle: [Function: canHandle]`

and

```
obj = {};
obj.canHandle = function (handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === that.type
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === that.name;
}
```

retuns `canHandle: [Function]`

Comment: Please post the code that you used to produce these outputs, and state what environment you are running it in.

Comment: Probably the first function is named and the second is not, but we can only guess.

Comment: Regard the `console.log` approch you always can use the `debugger` magic word for real debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first you are assigning a function to a property called canHandle. In this case the function has a name and that name is `canHandle`.

In the second you are creating an `anonymous function` and assigning it to the canHandle property of your object. This is why the second function does not have a name.

Answer (score 1):

it means canHandle is method of object

for example

```
const someObject = {
  canHandle() {}
};
```

you can call it someObject.canHandle()

Practically those both example are same ...
in first example you declared object with canHandle method..
and second example you decalerd object and later assigned canHandle metod of object